# Calcution's functionality & webapplication

Tags: calculator

Is there a application in Internet or a function in a calculator at windows 7 to make a caculation containing 400 and 360?

It is easier to calculate if numbers have low numbers.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=400!/360!/40!) will do it, getting the exact value.  It is approximately $1.97\cdot 10^{55}$

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know if there is a Alpha functionality for Excel? I tried but failed.

Comment: No, similar is available in Mathematica.  Because Excel does not do arbitrary precision calculations, it cannot do $400!$.  It can store this value, but you need to get it in range by dividing by $360!$.  You can use Stirling's approximation to get the logs of the factorials, then get the log of the binomial, then exponentiate.